# printing special characters without spaces

Tags: python, printing, special-characters

I made a for loop to write a little program that has an if condition.  I want to print a number and put it between '' without any space.  Here is a portion of my program :

```
for y in range(2):  

print('  if a ==','\'',y,'\'' ,'and',' b ==','\'',y,'\'',':')
```

My output is

- if a == '    0    ' and  b == '   0    ' :

  if a == '   1    ' and  b == '    1    ' :

but I want it to be :

- if a == '0' and  b == '0' :

  if a == '1' and  b == '1' :

without any spaces between the ' and the number.

Comment: assuming `y` is  a string, you can use `+` instead of `,` .even if it isnt, you can use `+` by enclosing your variable in a `str()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment. You can use `+` instead. However a much better way of "formatting" you `print` statements exactly the way you want is to use `.format`.

`print ('If a == '{0}' and b == '{0}'.format(str(y)))`